# How do I give permisison to read/write for a user to a folder owned by www-dat in /var/www/app?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, permissions, multiple-users

I have a folder: /var/www/app where my app is there.

Its owned by www-data:www-data.

I want to give another user (john) read/write access to the above folder (this is a FTP user ) while the www-data user continues to have normal access to the folder.

What should I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions.

1. If the "www-data" group has the read/write access of the the folder, you can add "john" to the "www-data" group.

`usermod -G www-data -a john`

2. If the `setfacl` command is available, using `setfacl -m u:john:rw -R /var/lib/app` to give authorization.

Comment: Could you please explain the 1st one .
the permission for the folder app is now : drwxr-s---

Comment: drwxr-s---indicates "www-data" group only has read access. The 1st solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I have tried with adding the user to the www-data group and providing 775 permission for the folder recursively.I was able to upload a file through FTP , but for the file uploaded the user and group ownership was john itself, where www-data wont get acess to the uplaod file , what to do here?

Comment: Did you run the FTP service daemon with user john as effective user? The uploaded file's owner and group would be the same user as FTP service runs with. Try run it with user "www-data".